# Use iTunes Library framework in Node.js/Electron app?

Tags: node.js, macos, electron, itunes

I am developing an Electron (Node.js) app that accesses the iTunes database. Before Catalina one could use an exported XML version of the database `iTunes Music Library.xml`. This was removed in Catalina where the iTunes library framework should be used instead https://developer.apple.com/documentation/ituneslibrary.

Is it possible to include this framework in my Electron or generally in a Node.js project and interact with it and if yes — how?

I scanned GitHub for modules or possible solutions but all of them rely on the old XML file.

Answer (score 2):

The only way I see is using a node native module. Apple uses Objectiv-C and every other language (javascript, python, etc) uses C or C++ bindings. Luckly, clang supports Objective-C++, which allows to mix C++ and Objective-C. A basic snippet that works looks like this (name it `readMusic.mm`. `mm` is the extension für Objectiv-C++)

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <iTunesLibrary/ITLibrary.h>
#import <iTunesLibrary/ITLibMediaItem.h>
#import <iTunesLibrary/ITLibArtist.h>
#include <node.h>
 

namespace demo {

using v8::FunctionCallbackInfo;
using v8::Isolate;
using v8::Local;
using v8::Array;
using v8::Object;
using v8::String;
using v8::Value;
using v8::Integer;

char const *emptyString = "";

void Method(const FunctionCallbackInfo<Value>& args) {
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init]; // Set this up so Cocoa works

    Isolate* isolate = args.GetIsolate(); // Setup for Javascript Connection
    Local<v8::Context> context = isolate->GetCurrentContext();
    Local<String> keyTitle = String::NewFromUtf8(isolate, "title").ToLocalChecked();
    Local<String> keyArtist = String::NewFromUtf8(isolate, "artist").ToLocalChecked();
    Local<String> keyFilePath = String::NewFromUtf8(isolate, "filePath").ToLocalChecked();
    Local<String> keyBpm = String::NewFromUtf8(isolate, "bpm").ToLocalChecked();


    NSError *error = nil;
    ITLibrary *library = [ITLibrary libraryWithAPIVersion:@"1.0" error:&error]; // Connect to iTunes / Music Library
    if (library)
    {
        NSArray *tracks = library.allMediaItems; // Load all Songs with Cocoa / Objective-C
        int size = [tracks count];

        Local<Array> jsSongsArr = Array::New(isolate, size); // Create Array for Javascript v8 engine

        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) { // Copy elements
            // Reading Data from Cocoa
            ITLibMediaItem *song = tracks[i];
            NSString *title = [song title];
            ITLibArtist *artist = [song artist];
            NSURL *location = [song location];

            // Convert it to c
            const char *titleInC = emptyString;
            const char *artistInC = emptyString;
            const char *filePathInC = emptyString;
            const long bpmInC = [song beatsPerMinute];

            if (title) {
                titleInC = [title UTF8String];
            }
            if (artist) {
                NSString *artistNSString = [artist name];
                if (artistNSString) {
                    artistInC = [artistNSString UTF8String];
                }
            }
            if (location) {
                NSString *locationNSString = [location absoluteString];
                if (locationNSString) {
                    filePathInC = [locationNSString UTF8String];
                }
            }

            Local<Object> jsSong = Object::New(isolate); // Create Javascript Object
            jsSong->Set(context, keyTitle, String::NewFromUtf8(isolate, titleInC).ToLocalChecked()).FromJust(); // Copy data in Javascript Object
            jsSong->Set(context, keyArtist, String::NewFromUtf8(isolate, artistInC).ToLocalChecked()).FromJust();
            jsSong->Set(context, keyFilePath, String::NewFromUtf8(isolate, filePathInC).ToLocalChecked()).FromJust();
            jsSong->Set(context, keyBpm, Integer::New(isolate, bpmInC)).FromJust();
            
            jsSongsArr->Set(context, i, jsSong).FromJust(); // Add the Object to Javascript Array
        }
        args.GetReturnValue().Set(jsSongsArr); // Set the return value of the function
    } else { // If error occurs
        args.GetReturnValue().Set(String::NewFromUtf8(isolate, [[error localizedDescription] UTF8String]).ToLocalChecked());
    }
}

void Initialize(Local<Object> exports) {
  NODE_SET_METHOD(exports, "readMusic", Method); // Tells node which function to use
}

NODE_MODULE(NODE_GYP_MODULE_NAME, Initialize) // Inits a native node module

}
```

Don't forget the NSAutoReleasePool when doing stuff like that. For the binding you need to set the -ObjC++ flags in your `binding.gyp`.

```
{
  "targets": [
    {
      "target_name": "addon",
      "sources": [ "readMusic.mm" ],
      "cflags!": [ "-ObjC++" ],
      "cflags_cc!": [ "-ObjC++" ],
      "libraries": [
          "/System/Library/Frameworks/iTunesLibrary.framework/Versions/Current/iTunesLibrary"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Then compile and codesign it (very important for distribution) via

```
HOME=~/.electron-gyp node-gyp rebuild --target=10.1.0 --arch=x64 --dist-url=https://electronjs.org/headers
codesign -s "YOUR DEVELOPER ID" build/Release/addon.node
```

And use it via

```
require("./build/Release/addon.node").readMusic();
```

Because of the dependence on native modules this is only compilable on Mac (https://www.electron.build/multi-platform-build).  Make sure to exclude that code on windows platforms.